# How to nest SliverList in Futurebuilder / Streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently refactoring my code from nested Listviews that shrinkwrap their children to a more performant version using a CustomScrollView with SliverList children.

My widget tree looks something like this:

CustomScrollView -> SliverList(with childBuilder delegate)->Futurebuilder -> SliverList(with childBuilder delegate), StreamBuilder -> SliverList(with childBuilder delegate), some other SliverLists

So the problem I am encountering is, that the Stream- and FutureBuilders expect a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList.

Error message:

```
A RenderConstrainedBox expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderConstrainedBox that expected a RenderBox child was created by: SizedBox ← FutureBuilder<dynamic> ← Column ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#7dc60] ← ⋯
The RenderSliverList that did not match the expected child type was created by: SliverList ← SizedBox ← FutureBuilder<dynamic> ← Column ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← Viewport ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<dynamic> FutureBuilder
```

I guess one way to solve this would be to wrap the entire CustomScrollView in the Future and StreamBuilder, but this would mean a lot of work since at least the FutureBuilder depends on the childBuilder delegate from the previous SliverList to access its futures.

Is there a way to solve this problem in another way?
Maybe a widget that wraps around the Sliverlist insinde the FutureBuilder to make it a box object instead of a sliver object?

Here is a bit of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  myFuture() async {
    return 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, indexx) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: myFuture(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Text(index.toString()),
                      );
                    }, childCount: 10));
                  }
                  return const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  );
                },
              );
            }, childCount: 10),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you include sample widget

Comment: actually you would need only one `StreamBuilder` that provides all the data and acts as a parent for `CustomScrollView` - you could use an [async generator](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#:~:text=Creating%20a%20stream%20from%20scratch,-One%20way%20to&text=The%20stream%20is%20created%20when,using%20yield%20or%20yield*%20statements.) to feed that `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly `FutureBuilder` inside `slivers`. All you need to make sure to return a sliver widget from FutureBuilder

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Text(""),
          );

        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(builder));
        return SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My problem is, that I need the futurebuilder to be wrapped in some kind of builder that can provide an index (listview.builder or SliverChildBuilderDelegate). But then I can not return a Sliver Widget from the Futurebuilder since the SliverList expects box widgets... I also cant return a ListView.builder since then the vertical viewport is given infinite hight (and shrinkwrapping would defeat the purpose).

Comment: you can follow pskink's comment, also it would be easier to get if you could include snippet that reproduce the same issue